# Update JSON data that is stored in Database

Tags: php, json

I have JSON data that is stored in a variable which is a set of permissions for a particular user. The JSON data however, is not stored in a file, it's just in a database column.

I've tried to look for a method of updating a permission (which is either true or false) but I've had no luck thus far. At the moment, I have something to the effect of;

*The raw JSON data...*

```
{
    "permissions": {
        "permission_1": true,
        "permission_2": false
    }
}
```

*Getting it out of the database...*

```
$permissions = json_decode($data, true);
```

How do I (using PHP) update the JSON data to say, update permission 2 to true? I'm using `json_decode()` when it comes out of the database and putting it into an array but that's only for using it. After that I'm lost as to how to update the value.

Comment: You would need to run an SQL (assuming) query in order to update the value in the database. This question is too broad for a single correct answer, but you're on the right track. Look into `json_encode`, `json_decode`, `serialize`, `unserialize`. Once you have the data updated, you can run a query to save it in the DB.

Comment: I was after Martin's answer. What I needed was to update the variable and then encode the JSON data again. All the other questions used a scenario where it was updating an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order:

- Extract column data from the database.

  ```
  "SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1"
  ```
- `JSON_decode` data into a set of PHP values/objects/arrays/whatever.

  ```
  $array = json_decode($OutputRow['column'],true);
  ```
- Update the value(s) you need to update.

  ```
  $array['permissions']['permission2'] = true;
  ```
- Recompile into a JSON string using `JSON_encode`.

  ```
  $data = json_encode($array);
  ```
- Update the database (SQL?) with the new JSON_encoded string.

  ```
  "UPDATE table SET column = :data WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1"
  ```

My examples use PDO and MySQL by reference but does not go into any details about database interaction as you've not given any details as to how you're reaching your database. It's ***only*** a ballpark rough example of how to do the points listed.

Comment: Seems pretty simple but just couldn't figure this out. Thanks that was what I was after.

Comment: @DanielJames it's always pretty simple... once you know. No worries. `:-)`